# c declaring initialized, const, array or array of strings

Tags: c, gcc

I need some array of array of const strings.
This compiles just fine in C

```
char* names[] = {"John", "Adrian", "Mary", NULL};
char* towns[] = {"Paris", "London", "Amsterdam", "Madrid", NULL};
char** test[] = {names, towns, NULL};
```

Is there a shorter way to do them all in one, like this?

```
char** test[] = {{"John", "Adrian", "Mary", NULL}, {"Paris", "London", "Amsterdam", "Madrid", NULL}, NULL};
```

Gives a

```
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) of array type from C99.

```
char** test[] = {(char*[]){"John", "Adrian", "Mary", NULL},
                 (char*[]){"Paris", "London", "Amsterdam", "Madrid", NULL},
                 NULL};
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain the cryptic compiler messages:

> warning: braces around scalar initializer
> error: initialization of 'char **' from incompatible pointer type 'char *'
> error: excess elements in scalar initializer

A "scalar" is C standard gibberish for a single item variable, either a plain variable or a pointer. As opposed to an "aggregate" which is an array or struct.

A `char** test[]` expects an initializer list either consisting of `char* []` arrays or `char**` items. (A `char* []` array will decay into a `char**` when used in most expressions.) But the initializers you provided are of type `char []`, decaying into `char*`.

The compiler thinks that `{"John", "Adrian", "Mary", NULL}` is the initializer to the first `char**` in your array. It thinks this is a single item surrounded by braces. Or well, `"John"` is one single item and the rest are too many items to initialize a single `char**`. Hence the messages saying "why did you use braces when you only intended to initialize one `char**`?" and "why did you give multiple initializers".

And then assigning a `char*` `"John"` to a `char**` is invalid C so the compiler gives a warning about incompatible pointer types as well.

---

One possible fix is to ditch the pointer-to-pointer and just do a plain "mangled" 1D array:

```
char* test[] = {"John", "Adrian", "Mary", NULL, "Paris", "London", "Amsterdam", "Madrid", NULL, NULL};
```

If you want to keep the "2D array-like" syntax with `char** []`, then each initializer must be an array of `char*`. One solution to that is to use compound literals as shown in the answer by @tstanisl. Or just stick to your original solution, there was nothing wrong with it.